# Orientdb Import csv to document Model

Tags: import, model, etl, orientdb, document

I'm trying to import a csv file to document Model in Orientdb using ETL
I don't know if this is correct as a newbie , and not a lot of documentation on the document model but What I tried is :

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": {
    "file": {
      "path": "C:/Users/M/Desktop/files/lact.csv"
    }
  },
  "extractor": 
{ "csv": 
      {  "separator": ",", 
         "nullValue": "NULL"
      }
  },
  "transformers": [
    {
      "log": {}
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/Model_doc",



       "dbType": "document",
      "classes": [
        {
          "name": "Annotations"
        },


      ]
    }
  },
  "end": []
}
```

I'm getting this saying  after displaying a parse of the content of the file:
[orientdb] DEBUG orientdb: found 0 documents in class 'null'

**Csv File**

```
"Entry","Entry_name","Status","Protein_names","Gene_names","Organism","Length","Cross_reference(STRING)"
"Q29836","1B67_HUMAN","reviewed","HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, B-67 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen B*67)","HLA-B HLAB","Homo sapiens (Human)","362","9606.ENSP00000399168;"
"P30501","1C02_HUMAN","reviewed","HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-2 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*2)","HLA-C HLAC","Homo sapiens (Human)","366",""
"P30508","1C12_HUMAN","reviewed","HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-12 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*12)","HLA-C HLAC","Homo sapiens (Human)","366",""
"Q29960","1C16_HUMAN","reviewed","HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-16 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*16)","HLA-C HLAC","Homo sapiens (Human)","366",""
"Q29865","1C18_HUMAN","reviewed","HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-18 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*18)","HLA-C HLAC","Homo sapiens (Human)","366",""
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the csv file? What version are you using? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I'm using 2.2.22 oientdb commnity version . As for the csv I edited the question

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, I have the same message:

```
[orientdb] DEBUG orientdb: found 0 documents in class 'null'
```

but I've been able to import all the data, as you can see from my screenshot.

[image]

to do that as @RobertoFranchini said, you have to add this:

```
 "transformers": [
{
  "log": {}
},
{
  "field": {
    "fieldName": "@class",
    "value": "Annotations"
  }
}
],
```

I made this little change to your csv file:

```
Entry,Entry_name,Status,Protein_names,Gene_names,Organism,Length,Cross_reference(STRING)
Q29836,1B67_HUMAN,reviewed,HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, B-67 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen B*67),HLA-B HLAB,Homo sapiens (Human),362,9606.ENSP00000399168
P30501,1C02_HUMAN,reviewed,HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-2 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*2),HLA-C HLAC,Homo sapiens (Human),366,
P30508,1C12_HUMAN,reviewed,HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-12 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*12),HLA-C HLAC,Homo sapiens (Human),366,
Q29960,1C16_HUMAN,reviewed,HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-16 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*16),HLA-C HLAC,Homo sapiens (Human),366,
Q29865,1C18_HUMAN,reviewed,HLA class I histocompatibility antigen, Cw-18 alpha chain (MHC class I antigen Cw*18),HLA-C HLAC,Homo sapiens (Human),366,
```

and all the data has been imported.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a class to the document, add the field transformer to the chain, just after log

```
"transformers": [
{
  "log": {}
},
{
  "field": {
    "fieldName": "@class",
    "value": "Annotations"
  }
}
],
```

Comment: Franchini ,did not work  I added the line yet the problem still persists

Comment: In your duplicated question you use class instead of @class . Please update this question.